# react-mounter Material-ui meteor using themes

Tags: meteor, reactjs, material-ui

I am just starting with meteor/flow-router/react-mounter and am running into an issue setting the theme for a component in Material-ui.

In Material-UI v 0.15.0 they no longer set the default them to lightBaseTheme so it has to be set at creation.

Here is a sample component.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Navigationclose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import NavigationMoreVert from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';


class Navbar extends React.Component {

    childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

    getChildContext() {
        return {muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme)};
    }

    render() {

        return (<AppBar
            title="Title"
            iconElementLeft={<IconButton><Navigationclose /></IconButton>}
            iconElementRight={
           <IconMenu
               iconButtonElement={
                <IconButton><NavigationMoreVert /></IconButton>
              }
               targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
              anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
          >
              <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh"/>
                <MenuItem primaryText="Help"/>
              <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out"/>
           </IconMenu>
        }
        />);
    }
}


export default Navbar;
```

Can anyone help me set the theme for a component using Material-UI, or have a working example

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this simple working [example](https://github.com/shinol/simple-todos)

Comment: The example doesn't use react-mounter from kadira. My issue was more so how to set the theme when using react-mounter